# inet_addr returns -1 for localhost

Tags: delphi, winsock, delphi-xe

Using Delphi XE and the winsock unit

I have the following code:

```
var
  fHost: AnsiString;
begin
  inet_addr(PAnsiChar(fhost));
```

`fHost` can be an ip address or a host name.

when `fhost = '127.0.0.1'` it works fine however, when `fHost = 'localhost'` the call fails and returns -1. I have noticed that in my complex app that `inet_addr` fails to resolve any host names and only works with ip addresses.

If I take this code out to a simple test app then resolving localhost (and host names) works fine.

I've tried adding the line `127.0.0.1 localhost` into the hosts file and that made no difference.

Why would this code in one application fail and in a simple test harness work every time?

Comment: BTW, -1 is INADDR_NONE, expected error return value

Comment: I have resolved this issue.

My application is converted from Delphi 2007 to Delphi XE

In Delphi 2007, winsock.pas defines INADDR_NONE = -1

For some unknown reason in Delphi XE, winsock.pas defines INADDR_NONE = DWORD($FFFFFFFF);

This means that my code to resolve localhost in case if (res = INADDR_NONE) then never got called.

Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 4):

Your test code is likely incorrect, `inet_addr` converts a string containing an IP address to a numeric value, it does *not* resolve hosts. Use `gethostbyname` for that.

Comment: This is my fault for typing that I wanted a resolved address. I don't. I want the correct result of `inet_addr`

Comment: @Paul Endersby: When you give `inet_addr` *anything* except a literal IP, it will return `INADDR_NONE` aka `-1`. `inet_addr` cannot be used to convert "localhost" - "localhost" isn't an IP.